# Git Workflow, reverting merge and reaplying it in future

Tags: git, version-control, merge, revert

Here is a workflow we use in our company:

1. Master is a branch which should alway stable and is used to build production.
2. When we develop new feature we create a feature branch from master.
3. We have many teams working on many features at same time.
4. When a feature is ready, Master is merged into feature branch (standard merge) and feature branch is bring tested on production like environment.
5. If Feature Branch is fine it is merged back to Master, Master goes through automatic tests and is builded to production.

Now lets imagine a situation where during a workflow and merging Feature Branches to Master, after few merges to Master we have to revert one of older ones.

How should we do it so Master will not be destabilised?
We also need to do it in a way allowing to remerge this reverted Feature Branch in the future.

Ps - doing reset --hard of Master and remerging everything that happens after merge of "faulty" Feature Branch is not an option here (too complex to recreate all merges).

Comment: this is a dupe of a number of other questions - https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this document explains everything:
https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt

Reverting is possible, but then a revert of the revert need to be done to bring back those changes.